# OpenCV: Grab HSV color and use it with inRange

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, python-3.4, opencv3.0

So I am trying to accomplish this using Python 3.4 with Numpy and OpenCV:

```
1) Grab pixel color in HSV format in desired area.
2) Use it with cv2.inRange
3) Track given object
```

Here is snippet of my code:

```
# Capture pixel color from HSV
ret, frame = cap.read()

frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 

height, width = frame.shape[:2]
color = hsv[int(width/2)][int(height/2)] # Grab pixel at center
```

My problem is that when I want to manually track red object, I need to  set inRange as follows:

```
lower_collor = np.array([0, 150, 150])
upper_collor = np.array([10, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_color, upper_color)
```

And it works (almost) perfectly, but when I try to grab color of red object with above code from pixel I get this value: `18 84 183`. So H and V values are +- OK, but S-value is completelly out of range.

I guess I just missing something, but I can not figure out what is it.